# 'mat-card' is not a known element, but I've used it on other pages

Tags: cordova, angular-material, angular10

I'm working on an Angular 10 (cordova) project that uses angular Marterial. I've created `login` and `register` pages, which use material components. But adding a new `users` page results in a `'mat-card' is not a known element` error (even though I've used them in the `login` and `register` pages). Deleting the `<mat-card>` element allows the app to compile (`ng build`) correctly.

The only difference with the `users` page is that it's lazy loaded within a `dashboard` module where the `login`, `register` and `dashboard` modules are all lazy loaded within `app-routing.module.ts`...

To get a full understanding of how my app is structured, I included all the important parts below. Please let me know if I'm missing anything. The basic idea is that I have a `AppMaterialModule` that I import into all my child modules, which are lazy loaded as needed.

All pages import `app-material.module.ts` which includes:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';

const matModules = [
  MatCardModule 
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...matModules
  ],
  exports: [
    ...matModules
  ]
})
export class AppMaterialModule { }
```

`app.module.ts` imports both `AppMaterialModule` and `AppRoutingModule`.

`app-routing.module.ts` has the following code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticatedGuardService } from './shared/authenticated-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/landing/landing.module').then(m => m.LandingModule) },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/register/register.module').then(m => m.RegisterModule) },
  { path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuardService], loadChildren: () => import('./pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard/users', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard/users' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`dashboard-routing.module.ts` has the following:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'users', loadChildren: () => import('../users/users-routing.module').then(m => m.UsersRoutingModule) }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Finally, `users.module.ts` has the following:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { UsersRoutingModule } from './users-routing.module';

import { UsersComponent } from './users.component';
import { AppMaterialModule } from '../../app-material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UsersComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    UsersRoutingModule,
  ]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

As you can see, I import `AppMaterialModule` into each module. I've referred back to a working Angular 9 project (Ionic) that uses a similar setup and it looks identical (except for required Angular9 vs Angular10 changes), so not sure what I'm doing wrong :(

Can anyone see what I've overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, my, god.

Within `dashboard-routing.module.ts` I was using `import('../users/users-routing.module').then(m => m.UsersRoutingModule)` instead of `import('../users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule)`.

A very expensive mistake.

Comment: ehhhhh. I also did the same wrong. I was very frustrated. thanks for doing the same wrong for me ):